# Dynamic profile2 fields - User can add more fields while registration

Tags: users

how to add dynamic user registration fields . I need a phone number field which can be added by users during registration by pressing "add more" button as many times he wants .

Is it possible ? or any other approach ?

thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible, that's the default behaviour for a multiple cardinality field. What problem are you having?

Comment: Where can i find this "multiple cardinality field" ; while creating a field in my profile i see basic options like , text , image , list etc .

Comment: The cardinality is part of the settings for every field type - edit any field, scroll to the bottom, and change "Number of Values" to "Unlimited"

Comment: thanks , i did;t think about that . can i have a another option in "multiple cardinality field" saying this phone number is "primary" and this is "secondary" ?

Comment: Why not have one field for the primary number, cardinality 1, and another optional field with unlimited cardinality for secondary numbers?

Comment: thanks @AlfredArmstrong :  this is what i did in the end :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [Field Collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module.